# Split a text file into blocks

Tags: java, string, file, text, split

I need to read a text file, and break the text into blocks of 6 characters (including spaces), pad zeroes to the end of text to meet the requirement.

I tried doing it and here is what I have done.

```
File file = new File("Sample.txt");
    String line;
    try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        line = sc.next();
        int chunk = line.length();
        int block_size=6;
        if((chunk%block_size) != 0)
        {
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(line);
            int val = chunk%block_size;
            for(int i=0; i<val; i++){
                sb.append(" ");
            }
           line = new String(sb.toString());
        }
        int group = line.length() / block_size;
        String[] b = new String[group];
        System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println(chunk);
        int j =0;
        for(int i=0; i<group;i++){
            b[i] = line.substring(j,j+block_size);
            j += block_size;
    }
        System.out.println("String after spliting is: ");
        for(int i=0; i<group;i++){
            System.out.println(b[i]);
        }

        }
    }
```

Now this works fine when the text in the input file has no spaces between words. But when I add spaces gives me a different output. I am stuck up at this point. Any suggestions on the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to write the solution for you, but I'd advise you that what you're trying to accomplish might be easier to do using a `BufferedReader` with a `FileReader` and by using `Reader.read(buf)` where buf is a char[6];